# Track User login and logout with sessiontracking using Spring

Tags: spring, session, spring-mvc, spring-security, sessionid

I'm using Spring MVC and have to implement session tracking through programatically.

When user logged in, check some info related to credentials and get the rememberedParameter(SessionId) from Oracle coherence and send it back to User, further requests from the same user should accompany by rememberedParameter so that session will be remembered for 30 mins..After 30 mins user has to be logged out and redirected to login page.

Above is my scenario, I could implement it manually through java program but is there any framework which will do it for me?

Will Spring Security will cover this scenario?

Pls advice me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Oauth framework..it is really good...